# 3-D Terrain effects for vectors in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, 3d, hillshade, shaded-relief

I'm a bit new to QGIS, and making a few maps of roads through mountains. I'm looking to have a 3-D effect within my 2-D map.

I got a DEM, made a hillshade, and blended a basemap over it.  [Nice tutorial for this](https://opengislab.com/blog/2018/3/20/3d-dem-visualization-in-qgis-30)

My raster has a nice 3-D effect of the terrain. Is there someway to get the same for the vector layer i.e. roads. as you can see in the image the road doesn't seem to be fitted/adjusted to the terrain.

I searched a bit got some clues of v.drape (couldn't get it to work) not even sure if it'd do what I want. And I believe 2.5D symbology is for polygons only. Kinda need some way to embed the Z values in the road shapefile or something similar.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want the road to be (somehow) visually "draped" over the hillshade. It also sounds like you're not exactly sure what that would look like. Do you have an example of another map that looks like what you want?

Comment: I have a few suggestions you can try in different combinations: make the road layer partially transparent; test out the different "blending modes" in the Layer rendering section of the style manager (for the road as well as the raster layers); make the hillshade partially transparent and move that layer above the road layer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking your example, I would guess that under:

*Right click on Layer* ->`Layer Properties` ->`3D View`

you need to change `Altitude clamping` mode of your vector (the road) from `Relative` to `Absolute`.

As it is now, it seems the road is represented at its absolute height *over* the terrain, which is not what you want.

[image]

Comment: I tried changing altitude clamping but it doesn't change anything at all.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you post (in the original question) your `3D View` settings?

Comment: I'm currently using no 3-D settings. I made a hillshade from a DEM which is giving the raster a 3-D effect (that's all). There's no actual 3-D involved.... The view in the image is 2-D

Comment: Duh, taking a closer look I see it is 2D, it seemed the road was floating. Than I don't understand your question at all: what are you trying to achieve?